How do I access a device inside a procedural proto node in the robot controller when the proto is regenerated mid-simulation?
Context: I've made a procedural proto node that contains several proto sensors. It works basically by having an MFNode field in the definition that I put my proto-gps in (that proto contains basically the webots default gps with custom default values and some models - it also exposes the sensor parameters like accuracy and noise etc), and in the main proto body there is some javascript code reading a boolean field value also in the proto definition. Depending on the value of this boolean, a node with "children IS protoGPS" (if protoGPS was the name of the MFNode field) may exist in the body or not, effectively making a toggle that will cause the sensor in that MFNode field to exist in the simulation or not. There are actually several sensors inside separate MFNode fields in this proto, I'm simplifying to just the gps for simplicity. My assumption is that this boolean checking is what causes the overall procedural proto node to regenerate any time the sensor parameters (like accuracy) in the protoGPS (in the MFNode field) are changed mid-simulation (even though the boolean doesn't change). This doesn't cause the parent robot node to regenerate, so the controller continues running (which I need).
When this happens, in my c++ controller code, I lose any updates I would get from that gps device (inside the protoGPS). Through a lot of testing, I was able to see that when it regenerates, robot->getNumberOfDevices() increases by the number of devices in the proto. My assumption is that this regeneration essentially creates a second set of devices for the newly generated proto node, which would make sense if it's intended to function like it's adding another node entirely. I know in Robot.cpp it states that // deleted devices are not removed from the C API list and don't affect the number of devices, so it would make sense that regenerating the proto node essentially doubles the number of devices on the robot.
Unfortunately, when actually going through the devices in the robot in the c++ controller with for (int i = 0; i < robot->getNumberOfDevices(); i++) {cout << robot->getDeviceByIndex(i)->getModel() << endl;} after changing the model field in the gps mid-simulation, instead of outputting both the old model field (from the old version of the device) and the new model field, it just outputs the old model field twice. The same behavior happens if I use getDeviceByIndex(i) and dynamic cast it to a GPS* object (can't use getGPS since the name is obviously the same before and after the regeneration) to get the actual GPS object and try to getValues from it; once the proto regenerates, the values no longer update and instead are stuck on the last values before it regenerated, which I would expect for one of the two sensors accessed, but it happens to both. They are also two independent tags and pointers.
Even weirder is depending on specific setup of where I put the completeSensor node with the MFNode gpsProto as children (ie whether it's in one of the parent robot's MFNode fields vs being inside a proto's MFNode field that inside the parent robot's MFNode field, and similar slight changes like that), it sometimes will just give the wb_device_init(): node not handled error instead of increasing the number of sensors. Also when this happens, I have to completely reload the webots window in order to see this sensor ever again in the robot - restarting the controller no longer sees it, which is very odd.
My question boils down to: how can I access the gps device in the c++ controller so I can get updated values from it when I change its fields mid-simulation, causing the procedural proto node to regenerate, since the updated gps doesn't seem to exist when going through robot->getDeviceByIndex(i)?
I've been trying to track down in the Webots source code where exactly this behavior comes from, and I've been unsuccessful so far, so I'm not sure if the duplicate of the old (no longer existent) device is intended somehow, or if it's overlooked, or if it's a bug, or if my specific implementation is causing unintended behavior somehow.
Similarly, while trying to debug this, I've also noticed that changing more than one field at once in the protoGPS mid-simulation (going step by step and changing two fields before the next step, causing it to regenerate twice) causes either the controller to crash with several wb_device_init(): node not handled errors, or just causes the whole Webots application to crash entirely (seems random whether it'll do one or the other). Not sure if the could help pin-point my main issue, or if it's another problem altogether.
Any help would be appreciated, this issue is causing me a lot of grief.
Edit: Through some further testing and simplification of the system, I'm able to track down that the node that regenerates and causes the issue is actually my 'completeSensor' proto, which is the node in the body with "children IS protoGPS" that may exist or not depending on a boolean. The contents of this proto node can be simplified to just a Pose in the body with 2 children: 1) another pose that has "children IS children" (children in the definition being the MFNode with the protoGPS), and 2) another proto that is basically a pose that imports 3d models for visuals. The second proto in its children (the one that imports the models) has a name field set with some javascript that accesses the fields object of children, to get the name of the protoGPS, which is what makes it a procedural proto node that regenerates when the gnss fields are edited. So I now know which proto regeneration causes my issue, but it's still the same issue with not seeing the edited gps device anywhere in the robot when the proto regens mid-simulation.
Regenerating proto for reference (it's hard to explain with words):
#VRML_SIM R2023b utf8
# template language: javascript

EXTERNPROTO "ImportModel.proto"

PROTO CompleteSensor [
    field SFVec3f translation 0 0 0
    field SFRotation rotation 0 0 1 0
    field MFNode sensors []
]
{
    Pose {
        translation IS translation
        rotation IS rotation
        children [
            Pose {
                children IS sensors
            }
         %< for (let i = 0; i < fields.sensors.value.length; i++) { >%
                ImportModel {
                    modelFolder "%<=fields.sensors.value[i].fields.name.value>%"
                }
         %< } >%
        ]
    }
}

